# How can I use Postgres "ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT" with "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Postgres 10

I am trying to use "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" to make a work queue in Postgres.

My goal is to be able to set status to 'complete' or 'failed' as the outcome by using "ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT;" in the event that processing fails.

I expected the code below  to result in a final status of "failed", but it appears the final status is "waiting".

```
BEGIN;
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
      SELECT id
      INTO foo
      FROM jobs
      WHERE status = 'waiting'
      AND status != 'failed'
      ORDER BY created ASC
      FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
      LIMIT 1;

    UPDATE jobs SET status = 'failed' WHERE id = (SELECT id from foo) RETURNING *;
    SAVEPOINT blah;
    UPDATE jobs SET status = 'complete' WHERE id = (SELECT id from foo) RETURNING *;


ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT blah;
```

Can anyone please suggest what I can do to use either COMMIT to for status to be 'complete' or ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT blah for statgus to be 'failed'?

thanks!

Comment: Debug it. Either you rolled back in the end, or your first update did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you never committed at all, so from the outside no changes will be visible until you do so.